# Is the last step in the Christofides' algorithm necessary

Tags: algorithms, traveling-salesman

I am using [Christofides' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm) to calculate the best route from one location to another given multiple nodes on a map that the route *must* pass through.

The last step in the algorithm requires the route to connect back to the first node, right?

Is this step necessary? If no, why?

Edit:

I essentially want the data that can achieve the following: [image: Route between nodes on a map]

Each red node must be visited once before the green node, and the illustration assumes the start of the route is directly on top of a red node but it could be anywhere (assuming these are directions).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you are trying to achive, and how you apply the Christofide's algorithm? The Christofide's algorithm is not an algorithm that finds the best route between two nodes, it finds an approximation to a TSP.
Also what do you mean with *last step*? The last step in the Christofide's algorithm is to transform the Eulerian circuit into the actual traveling route. The Eulerian circuit is not a path between two nodes. And in fact it can visit some nodes multiple times. So you probably want to transform the Eulerian circuit somehow, and not just skip the step.

Comment: See also: [David Eisenstat's SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65604512).

Comment: Christofides' algorithm is designed to find a closed tour. It seems like you're interested in a slightly different problem. So you should rephrase your question as follows: is there a variant of Christofides' algorithm which finds a path from $x$ to $y$ which contains each vertex exactly once (assuming this is the problem you're interested in).

Comment: Please describe clearly the problem that you are aiming to solve. Don't assume that we know what TSP is.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What is the input, and what is the required output?

Comment: The input is a set of nodes on a graph (an implementation would be similar to the illustration in the question), and the required output is the shortest path that visits every specified node before finally reaching the specified end node. Christofide's algorithm doesn't seem to solve my problem after looking at it in more detail, what other agorithms would you suggest looking at? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: So you have a set of points $X$, a designated point $x \in X$, a metric on $X$ satisfying the triangle inequality, and are looking for a walk that visits all points in $X$ and ends at $x$.

Comment: Furthermore, the points $X$ are actually locations on the plane, and the metric is the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Your problem is very similar to the so-called *messenger problem* or *wandering salesman problem*. You can reduce it to the usual problem by adding a new vertex $y$, an edge $(x,y)$ with weight $-M$ (for large $M$), and zero weight edges between $y$ and all other vertices. An optimal tour will include the edge $(x,y)$, and after removing it you get a tour of the type you are aiming at. However, this is no longer planar TSP. (If you don't like negative weights, just add $M$ to all weights.)

Comment: Cross-posted on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65604190/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Please revise the question based on the feedback you've received in the comments.  Don't respond in the comments -- instead, we want you to improve the question.  Please don't use "edit:" or just append more information: think about how to formulate your question so it is self-contained and is understandable to someone who encounters this page for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.