# The shortest path that visits every specified node before finally reaching the specified end node?

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, traveling-salesman

After asking another question([Is the last step in the Christofides' algorithm necessary](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/134049/is-the-last-step-in-the-christofides-algorithm-necessary?noredirect=1#comment282424_134049)), I have decided Christofide's algorithm probably doesn't solve the problem I'm facing.

Is there any algorithms that would best suit this problem?

> The input is a set of nodes on a graph (an implementation would be similar to the illustration in the question), and the required output is the shortest path that visits every specified node before finally reaching the specified end node.

Comment: is the node sequence in order? if not then you are in traveling salesman territory (NP complete)

Comment: Can you link to or credit the source of all copied material?

Comment: It's my material so no need @D.W.

Comment: @ratchetfreak the node sequence is whatever makes the path from a starting node to an end node the shortest

Comment: What does "an implementation would be similar to the illustration in the question" mean?  What is the illustration that is referred to?  Please [edit] your question to make it self-contained so we can understand what is being asked without having to click on links.  Don't just copy-paste from your other question without context; think about how to write this question so it will be understandable to someone who encounters this page without having read your other question first.

Comment: Rather than responding with comments, please [edit] the question so it has all the information needed and so it reads well for someone who encounters the question for the first time.  Then, flag the comments as no longer needed.  We want people to be able to understand what is being asked without having to read the comments.  Thank you!

Comment: Here is my comment on your previous post: Your problem is very similar to the so-called messenger problem or wandering salesman problem. You can reduce it to the usual problem by adding a new vertex , an edge (,) with weight − (for large ), and zero weight edges between  and all other vertices. An optimal tour will include the edge (,), and after removing it you get a tour of the type you are aiming at. However, this is no longer planar TSP. (If you don't like negative weights, just add  to all weights.)

Comment: How do i make this the accepted answer?@YuvalFilmus